# Does current fuel shortage in Mexico impact taxi availability and pricing?

Tags: mexico, taxis

Does the current fuel shortage in central Mexico ([as reported by BBC](https://www.bbc.com/news/world-latin-america-46939165) for instance) - particularly in Jalisco - have an impact on taxi availability and prices?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was in Jalisco on February 8th 2019 and took an Uber. There was no fuel surcharge but I also believe the fuel shortage had ended by then.